# Adding overload changes which overload is selected

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how the overload selection rules result in the following (unintuitive) behavior. When I have the following functions:

```
#include <iostream>

// Overload 1
template<class T>
void write(T data)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(T data)" << std::endl;
}

// Overload 2
template<class T, class ...U>
void write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  int j = 0;
  write(j);
  return 0;
}
```

The `void write(T data)` overload (Overload 1) is selected. I think that makes sense to me: the candidates for overload selection are `void write<T>(T)` `T = int` and `void write<T,U>(T&)` `T = int, U = <>`. Both `write(T)` and `write(T&)` would be equally specialized, but Overload 2 has an empty parameter pack so Overload 1 is selected. However, if I add a third overload:

```
#include <iostream>

// Overload 0
void write(const int& data)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(const int& data)" << std::endl;
}

// Overload 1
template<class T>
void write(T data)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(T data)" << std::endl;
}

// Overload 2
template<class T, class ...U>
void write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)
{
  std::cout << "Called write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  int j = 0;
  write(j);
  return 0;
}
```

Then all of a sudden `void write(T&& obj, U&&... objs)` (Overload 2) is what gets called. Why does adding an overload that doesn't get selected change which overload actually does get selected?

If the only candidates were `void write<T,U>(T&)` `T = int, U = <>` and `void write(const int&)` I understand why `void write<T,U>(T&)` would be selected, so perhaps something about adding the extra overload prevents `void write(T data)` from participating on overload selection? If so why?

Since this seems to be compiler specific behavior this was observed on gcc 7.3.0.

Some more interesting behavior:
If the functions are reordered such that the new overload is placed between the original two (i.e. Overload 1, then Overload 0, then Overload 2) then gcc rejects it with `call of overloaded ‘write(int&)’ is ambiguous`. If the functions are reordered such that the new overload is last (i.e. Overload 1, then Overload 2, then Overload 0) then `write(const int& data)` is selected.

Comment: FWIW, clang rejects the second code block for an ambiguity while MSVS compiles but displays `Called write(T data)`

Comment: gcc uses #2 overload whereas clang reject as ambiguous: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da965c764d00fa09).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a GCC bug:

Overloads are:

- Overload 0: `write(const int&)`
- Overload 1: `write(T) [T=int] -> write(int)`
- Overload 2: `write(T&&,U&&...) [T=int&,U=[]] -> write(int&)`

Overload 0 is a better match than overload 1 because overload 0 is not a template functions specialization.

Overload 1 is a better match than overload 2 because overload 1 is a function template more specialized than overload 2.

Overload 2 is a better match than overload 0 because the cv qualifier of the parameter type of overload 2 `int&` is a subset of the one of overload 0: `const int&`.

So the call is ambiguous as reported by Clang.

---

To simplify, the best viable function is evaluate here in 4 steps here, when comparing two functions:

1. Check which is the best conversion sequence (all conversions are the identity conversion here), then if the conversion ranks are the same:
2. Check if between two reference bindings one is better than the other, then if one is not a reference binding or the two bindings are not differentiable,
3. Check if one of the function is a template specialization and the other is not, then if the two are template specializations
4. Check if one of the specializations is more specialized than the other.